# Will it cause a memory leakage on using free() to deallocate a heap allocated variable by new operator?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
int* integer = new int{10};
cout << *integer << endl;
free(integer);
cout << *integer << endl;
```

Output:

```
10
0
```

According to the code I've tested on my machine, It's quite obvious that the allocated memory is being successfully deallocated by using `free()`

But there are articles on the internet that discourages the use of the `new` operator and deallocation with `free()`

Are there any possibilities of memory leakage, if yes. Can anyone paste an example code where this type of leakage happens

Comment: It would if they werent ints, if you newed a bunch of std::string and then freed that array you'd leak because the dtor of those strings wouldn't get called.

Comment: In a word: **don't**!

Comment: Freeing `new`'ed memory with `free()` is **undefined behavior**. It is *possible* that `new` could be using `malloc()` internally, but don't rely on that. And `free()` will certainly not call any destructors on non-trivial types. So, always use `delete` to free `new`'ed memory.

Comment: `new` is not required to use `malloc`. Typically it does, but unless you have an absolutely compelling reason to break the C++ memory allocation model, use `delete` for memory that you got with `new` and `delete[]` for memory that you got with `new[]`.

Answer (score 1):

> Will it cause a memory leakage on using free() to deallocate a heap allocated variable by new operator?

It will cause undefined behaviour. Technically, memory leak is included in the set of all behaviours and thus it can be part of any outcome, but the memory leak is really the least of your worries in this case.

Let me be clear: Don't ever call `free` on anything that wasn't returned by `malloc` (or the other related C functions).

Accessing the object after its lifetime and storage duration has ended also has undefined behaviour. Don't ever do that either.

> Can anyone paste an example code where this type of leakage happens

Technically, you didn't delete what you new'd, so the program that you show is an example of program with memory leak. Interestingly, having undefined behaviour technically means that the memory leak doesn't necessarily happen. Regardless, you didn't demonstrate the lack of memory leak in your program, so there is no reason to assume that there isn't a leak.

> The value pointed by a is set to 0. Why ?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> And my code compiled fine

That's not a proof of lack of memory leak.

Comment: Is there a memory leakage in my code. Because after the ```free()```. The value pointed by ```a``` is set to 0.  Why ? And my code compiled fine

Comment: @ArtazaSameen `Is there a memory leakage in my code.` You used `new`. You didn't use `delete`, nor anything that would `delete` indirectly. Therefore you have a memory leak.

Comment: Then why ```a``` is set to 0. If memory wasn't freed

Comment: But the big point is don't focus on the memory leak. The leak is only a single possible manifestation of the undefined behaviour that infests the program. Maybe the program gives you the results you desire. Maybe it doesn't. Maybe today it does and tomorrow it won't. Maybe a few moments after running the program you get a knock on the door and find a large man asking if you are Sarah Connor. You can't win with undefined behaviour.

Comment: [Some handy reading.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt)